# MultipartEntityBuilder adds Content-Disposition header to binary file and corrupts it

Tags: java, rest, multipartform-data

I have a Java snippet of code which sends a binary file through the web to a REST client, unfortunately the multipartEntityBuilder which encodes the binary file adds some headers which corrupt the file, for instance it adds a Content-Disposition which is not present in the original file.

How can I fix this?

```
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(getRemoteUrlString() + "/webresources/file/upload");
MultipartEntityBuilder multipartEntityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
multipartEntityBuilder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.STRICT);
multipartEntityBuilder.setBoundary("custyom-mimetype-boundary");
multipartEntityBuilder.addPart("fileName", (StringBody) valuesList.get(0));
multipartEntityBuilder.addPart("file", (FileBody) valuesList.get(1));
httpPost.setEntity(multipartEntityBuilder.build());
httpPost.setEntity(multipartEntityBuilder.build());
HttpResponse response = null;
try
    {
       response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
    }
catch (IOException ex)
    {     
            }
```

Comment: a quick browse through the documentation http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/mime/MultipartEntityBuilder.html  shows there's a addBinaryBody which might be what you need. have you tried this? it seems to have the content type, filename, file already.

Comment: the addBinaryBody still adds the headers, I also tried with different setMode() options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only solution I found was to leave the headers on the sending side and modify the receiving side, apparently the readBodyData function also reads the headers if you don't first read the headers and discard them.

```
//We read uselessHeaders otherwise readBodyData includes them and corrupts some files
String uselessHeaders = multipartStream.readHeaders();
multipartStream.readBodyData(byteArrayOutputStream);
```